# How to update a JPA entity using Querydsl?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to query JPA with Querydsl (4.1.4) as written here 
http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration . I use Hibernate (5.2.12.Final) as the JPA backend. I generate Querydsl query types from the JPA annotated classes using the `apt-maven-plugin` with the `com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor` processor.

I have an issue while updating an entity : the updated value does not show up in the Java code. Here is the relevant code snippet that updates a boolean property (named `success`) in the Entity :

```
    final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = PersistenceTestUtils.buildEntityManagerFactory();
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    final EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    final QJpaUpdateRound qJpaUpdateRound = QJpaUpdateRound.jpaUpdateRound;
    final JPQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);

    final QJpaUpdateRound qJpaUpdateRound = QJpaUpdateRound.jpaUpdateRound;
    final JPQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    final long roundId = 3L;

    System.out.println("Original " +originalRound);

    queryFactory //
        .update(qJpaUpdateRound) //
        .set(qJpaUpdateRound._success, true) //
        .where(qJpaUpdateRound._id.eq(roundId)) //
        .execute();

    // entityManager.clear(); // Workaround

    // Fetch the updated value
    final UpdateRound updatedRound = queryFactory //
        .selectFrom(qJpaUpdateRound) //
        .where(qJpaUpdateRound._id.eq(roundId)) //
        .fetchOne();
    transaction.commit();
    System.out.println("Updated "+ updatedRound);
```

This prints :

> Original JpaUpdateRound{id=3; instant=2017-11-06T19:27:01.141Z;
>   success=false}
>  Updated JpaUpdateRound{id=3;
>   instant=2017-11-06T19:27:01.141Z; success=false}

Also, an identity test on `originalRound` and `updatedRound` shows that both variables are the same instance.

I checked in the database : the value is really updated. And if I uncomment the following line

```
    entityManager.clear(); // Workaround
```

The program prints

> Original JpaUpdateRound{id=3; instant=2017-11-06T19:39:01.038Z;
>   success=false}
>  Updated JpaUpdateRound{id=3;
>   instant=2017-11-06T19:39:01.038Z; success=true}

which is the result I expect.

It seems that the entity cache does not get updated when the Querydsl update is performed. Thus, it only returns the original Java object.

Why ? How can I synchronize the JPA backend and Querydsl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is no other way than manually tell the entity manager that it should refresh its data. Whether using `entityManager.refresh(entity)` on each entity that needs to be reloaded from the database; whether by clearing the whole entity manager cache by calling `entityManager.clear()`.

See [Force refresh of collection JPA entityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089177/force-refresh-of-collection-jpa-entitymanager#15239112)

Comment: This is the best solution. Also note that entityManager.flush() does not work either.